# Difference between override and rewrite in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Is both term override and rewrite are same in Magento. I have searched alot for this but not found any answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Short answer: yes, though it depends on who you talk to.*

**All rewrites are overrides, but not all overrides are rewrites**. A **rewrite** in Magento *should* only refer to a configuration-based class overrides. Factory methods are used by the framework to instantiate the MVC types:

- `Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock()`
- `Mage::helper()`
- `Mage::getModel()`
- `Mage::getResourceModel()`
- etc....

These methods generally match a class group (e.g. `catalog`) to a class prefix (e.g. `Mage_Catalog_Model`) in order to instantiate a particular class (e.g. `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')` yields  `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`). This mapping allows for developers to specify a certain xpath associated with the class argument (e.g. `'catalog/product'` & `global/models/catalog/rewrite/product`) to specify an alternate class to instantiate. From there it's the responsibility of the developer to use inheritance as appropriate to achieve the proper overriding & extending behavior.

There are other mechanisms for achieving overrides, the most common of which is the so-called "include path hack", which allows for classes from "lower" autoload directories to be (re)defined in higher-level directories in the following order of precedence (note that *app/code/local/*):

- *app/code/community/*
- *app/code/core/*
- *lib/*

This style of override should be considered a last-case means of changing core code. It has legitimate use cases (especially for obeying DRY), but may be non-obvious in an upgrade.